# Retrieving and displaying data from Wordpress database

Tags: php, html, wordpress

At the moment, I have created a code that retrieves data from the database and displays it. However, for some reason, I cannot see the files I want to retrieve on my page. My goal is that the data gets retrieved from the database, and is displayed on the webpage. I do not need to make a connection with the database since Wordpress does that automatically.

My code:

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
// this adds the prefix which is set by the user upon instillation of wordpress
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpex_programma";
// this will get the data from my table
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wpex_programma" );
?>
<!--This will display my files-->
<ul>
<?php foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){ ?>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->column_name;?></li>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->another_column_name;?></li>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->as_many_columns_as_you_have;?></li>
<?php 
}
?>
</ul>
```

My question: the data is not shown and I believe it is not retrieved. How can I fix that?

My database structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example code that will get the data and then display it

```
global $wpdb;
// this adds the prefix which is set by the user upon instillation of wordpress
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpex_programma";
// this will get the data from your table
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
?>
<ul>
foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){ ?>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->id;?></li>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->naam;?></li>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->as_many_columns_as_you_have;?></li>
<?php 
}
?>
```

[Class Reference/wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

1. Make sure you have a database created,
2. Make sure you are adding correct table_name,
3. Make sure you have data inserted in table.

Comment: I already have data in my table. My table is wpex_programma. However, it still will not display anything.

Comment: Would you please add to question your table structer, and do you get any error or message ?

Comment: Yes, I added it.

Comment: Copy the codes in answer I just edited. make sure if your table name is correct. and table prefix match or you are not adding prefix twice.

Comment: The code is the same as mine. You forgot the ````</ul>````. Also, my table name is wpex_programma. It is correct

Comment: Well codes in answer works fine here, my table name is **posts** without table prefix `demo_` wp auto inserts prefix infront of table name. check refence url in answer.

Comment: So you used my code and it works? Did you change the $retrieved_data variable?

Comment: I used my own codes not yours and yes they work fine. I just changed this `$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpex_programma";` to this `$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";` and column names to mines. my prefix is demo. add your table name into codes without prefix, wp will get prefix automoticaly

Comment: Yes, but they are mostly the same. Should I get rid of the prefix?

Comment: So this line: ````$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpex_programma";````

Comment: Try this one `$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "programma";`

Answer (score 1):

You can check the data from your database table. In PHP MySQL database. you can find the table name after the prefix of the table which you have decided while installing the WordPress. there should be your column name exact. with the table name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is correct but problem is in prefix in table name.

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpex_programma";

wpex_ is your table prefix name that you can get by using **$wpdb->prefix** so just remove wpex_ from table name.

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "programma";
```

or

```
$table_name = "wpex_programma";
```

if you have added different custom prefix name rather than have in other default tables, in this case,

$wpdb->prefix does not work for your custom table.

You can check wordpress prefix table name in wp-config.php

```
$table_prefix = 'wpex_';
```

and this name is different from your custom tables prefix than use like this:

```
$table_name = "wpex_programma";
```

and is it same in both your custom table and wordpress default tables than use like this:

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "programma";
```